# Highlight gridview row based on column value which is null

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to highlight gridview rows based on it's value on db..There is  a column name checkout.If the column is NULL then background color of row is red.If it has value then the background color is blue..So far this is what I have tried.Thank you in advance

```
Sub barapp_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        If e.Row.DataItem("CheckOut") Is Nothing Then


            e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        End If

    End If
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I don't know exact syntax of VB but i hope this will guide you.

```
Sub barapp_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)

If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

   Dim rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
   Dim CheckOut = rowView["CheckOut"].ToString();

    If CheckOut Is Nothing Then
        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red

    End If

End If
```

Comment: hello sir..your code working..but it highlights all the row..everything turn into yellow color..I just want to highlight the row which it's checkout date is null in database..? any idea sir ?

Comment: Ok then remove the else part then only those rows will be highlighted where date is null.

Comment: If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

            Dim rowView = e.Row.DataItem
            Dim CheckOut = rowView("CheckOut").ToString()

            If CheckOut Is Nothing Then
                e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red

            End If



        End If

Comment: I couldn't figure out sir..Not prompting errors also..Is there any other way?

Comment: Now are the rows with `NULL` values being colored red or not ?

Comment: I changed it as "Is DBNull.Value" and now it's working finely sir..Thank you :)